# CSS Animated Progress Bar with box-shadow / glowing / neon effect

Tags: html, css, geometry, progress

I have the below example, where I'm trying to make the neon effect on the animated progress bar like on the above lines and text.
It's seems I'm unable to achieve a clean neon effect on the animated circle with css.

html

```
<div class="lines">
        <div class="box1 montserrat">Text</div>
        <div class="box2 montserrat">Text</div>
        <div class="box3 neon_text cyan montserrat">11</div>
        <div class="box4"><hr class="cyan line"  ></div>
        <div class="box5 neon_text purple montserrat">9</div>
        <div class="box6 "><hr class="purple line"></div>
        <div class="box1 montserrat">Text</div>
        <div class="box2 montserrat">Text</div>
        <div class="box3 neon_text pink montserrat">10</div>
        <div class="box4"><hr class="pink line"></div>
        <div class="box5 neon_text blue montserrat">8</div>
        <div class="box6"><hr class="blue line"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper" data-anim="base wrapper">
  <div class="circle" data-anim="base left"></div>
  <div class="circle" data-anim="base right"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
body {  
  background: black;
  font-family: 'Montserrat'
}
 
.line {
  width:150px;
  height: 6px;
  border: none !important; 
  background: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.line.blue{
  box-shadow:
  inset 0 0 1px #008aff,
  inset 0 0 2px #008aff,

  0 0 1px white,
  0 0 6px #008aff,
  0 0 7px #008aff,
  0 0 8px #008aff,
  0 0 9px #008aff;
}

.line.purple{
  box-shadow:
  inset 0 0 1px #991bfa,
  inset 0 0 2px #991bfa,

  0 0 1px white,
  0 0 6px #991bfa,
  0 0 7px #991bfa,
  0 0 8px #991bfa,
  0 0 9px #991bfa;
}

.line.pink{
  box-shadow:
  inset 0 0 1px #f55497,
  inset 0 0 2px #f55497,

  0 0 1px white,
  0 0 6px #f55497,
  0 0 7px #f55497,
  0 0 8px #f55497,
  0 0 9px #f55497;
}

.line.cyan{
  box-shadow:
  inset 0 0 1px #17c3b2,
  inset 0 0 2px #17c3b2,

  0 0 1px white,
  0 0 6px #17c3b2,
  0 0 7px #17c3b2,
  0 0 8px #17c3b2,
  0 0 9px #17c3b2;
}

.neon_text{
  font-size:18px;
}

.neon_text.cyan{
  color:white;
  text-shadow:
  0 0 2px white,
  0 0 6px #17c3b2,
  0 0 8px #17c3b2,
  0 0 9px #17c3b2,
  0 0 10px #17c3b2,
  0 0 11px #17c3b2,
  0 0 13px #17c3b2,
  0 0 14px #17c3b2,
  0 0 15px #17c3b2;
}

.neon_text.purple{
  color:white;
  text-shadow:
  0 0 2px white,
  0 0 6px #991bfa,
  0 0 8px #991bfa,
  0 0 9px #991bfa,
  0 0 10px #991bfa,
  0 0 11px #991bfa,
  0 0 13px #991bfa,
  0 0 14px #991bfa,
  0 0 15px #991bfa;
}

.neon_text.pink{
  color:white;
  text-shadow:
  0 0 2px white,
  0 0 6px #f55497,
  0 0 8px #f55497,
  0 0 9px #f55497,
  0 0 10px #f55497,
  0 0 11px #f55497,
  0 0 13px #f55497,
  0 0 14px #f55497,
  0 0 15px #f55497;

}


.neon_text.blue{
  color:white;
  text-shadow:
   0 0 2px white,
  0 0 6px #008aff,
  0 0 8px #008aff,
  0 0 9px #008aff,
  0 0 10px #008aff,
  0 0 11px #008aff,
  0 0 13px #008aff,
  0 0 14px #008aff,
  0 0 15px #008aff;
}




.lines{
  display:grid;
  margin-right:5%;
  width:100%;
}

.box1{
  justify-self: center;
   grid-column-start: 2;
   grid-column-end: 2;
}

.box2{
  justify-self: center;
   grid-column-start: 4;
   grid-column-end: 4;
}

.box3{
   grid-column-start: 1;
   grid-column-end: 1;
}
.box4{
   justify-self: start;
   grid-column-start: 2;
   grid-column-end: 2;
}
.box5{
   grid-column-start: 3;
   grid-column-end: 3;
}
.box6{
   justify-self: start;
   grid-column-start: 4;
   grid-column-end: 4;
}



.wrapper {
  width: 200px; /* Set the size of the progress bar */
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute; /* Enable clipping */
  clip: rect(0px, 200px, 200px, 100px); /* Hide half of the progress bar */
  margin-top: 50px;
}
/* Set the sizes of the elements that make up the progress bar */
.circle {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border: 10px solid white;
  box-shadow:
  inset 0 0 1px white,
  inset 0 0 6px #17c3b2,
  inset 0 0 7px #17c3b2,
  inset 0 0 8px #17c3b2,
  inset 0 0 9px #17c3b2,
  
  0 0 1px white,
  0 0 6px #17c3b2,
  0 0 7px #17c3b2,
  0 0 8px #17c3b2,
  0 0 9px #17c3b2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0px, 100px, 200px, 0px);
}
/* Using the data attributes for the animation selectors. */
/* Base settings for all animated elements */
div[data-anim~=base] {
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;  /* Only run once */
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* Hold the last keyframe */
  -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear; /* Linear animation */
}

.wrapper[data-anim~=wrapper] {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.01s; /* Complete keyframes asap */
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s; /* Wait half of the animation */
  -webkit-animation-name: close-wrapper; /* Keyframes name */
}

.circle[data-anim~=left] {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 6s; /* Full animation time */
  -webkit-animation-name: left-spin;
}

.circle[data-anim~=right] {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s; /* Half animation time */
  -webkit-animation-name: right-spin;
}
/* Rotate the right side of the progress bar from 0 to 180 degrees */
@-webkit-keyframes right-spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
/* Rotate the left side of the progress bar from 0 to 360 degrees */
@-webkit-keyframes left-spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
/* Set the wrapper clip to auto, effectively removing the clip */
@-webkit-keyframes close-wrapper {
  to {
    clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vyo07kLs/67/

Could you please help me with that ?
I have looked all over the internet , but wasn't able to find an example including the box-shadow on the animated circle.

Comment: Check this pen `https://codepen.io/html-mentor/pen/Poqwxxz`. Are u trying something similar?

Comment: Thanks , I checked that one as well , but it uses the gradient effect , while I want to use a single color with a box-shadow effect on the circle line.

Comment: this might work , but I'm unable to make it animate from 0 deg to 360 deg like in my initial example . Here is what I were able to achieve : https://jsfiddle.net/zlobul/9ayf7L2p/75/

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve it using an SVG and definign the required colors there :

HTML

```
<div class=skill> 
  <div class=outer> 
    <div class=inner> 
      <div id="number">
        0
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="160px" height="160px">
         <defs>
            <linearGradient id="GradientColor">
               <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white" />
               <stop offset="100%" stop-color="white" />
            </linearGradient>
            
    <filter id="neon-glow" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
       <!-- blur the text at different levels-->
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="1" result="blur1"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="3" result="blur3"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="4" result="blur4"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" result="blur5"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" result="blur8"/>
      <!-- merge all the blurs except for the first one -->
      <feMerge result="blur-merged">
        <feMergeNode in="blur3"/>
        <feMergeNode in="blur4"/>
        <feMergeNode in="blur5"/>
        <feMergeNode in="blur8"/>
      </feMerge>
      <!-- recolour the merged blurs red-->
      <feColorMatrix result="cyan-blur" in="blur-merged" type="matrix"
                     values="0.09 0   0   0   0
                        0   0.76  0   0   0
                        0   0   0.70  0   0
                        0   0   0   1   0 "/>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="cyan-blur"/>       <!-- largest blurs coloured red -->
        <feMergeNode in="blur1"/>          <!-- smallest blur left white -->
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>  <!-- original white text -->
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
         </defs>
         <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="60" stroke-linecap="round" />

 </svg>


</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
  background:black;
}

.skill{
 width: 160px;
 height:160px;
 /* background: gray; */
 position: relative;
}

.outer{
   width: 160px;
   height:160px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   padding: 20px;
}

.inner{
   width: 120px;
   height:120px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   display:flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}

#number {
  font-weight:600;
  font-size:30px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow:
  0 0 1px white,
  0 0 6px #17c3b2,
  0 0 7px #17c3b2,
  0 0 8px #17c3b2,
  0 0 9px #17c3b2;
}

circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: url(#GradientColor);
  filter: url(#neon-glow);
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-dasharray:440;
  stroke-dashoffset: 440;
  animation: anim 2s linear forwards;
}

svg{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}


@keyframes anim{
  100% {
     stroke-dashoffset:0;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zlobul/nbomfr5x/303/